# How to show two or more non-overlapping label in a same position

Tags: plotting, labeling

I have such callout

```
call = {Callout[{756., 2047.5}, 1], Callout[{821.21, 2041.23}, 2], 
   Callout[{1057.63, 2030.22}, 4], Callout[{1057.63, 2030.22}, 6], 
   Callout[{1327.12, 2044.06}, 7]};
```

Note I cannot show two different labels in one position

```
ListPlot[call]
```

[image]

Actually, the following plot is expected
[image]

Comment: `newcalls=Join@@Replace[GatherBy[call, First], {Callout[a__],Callout[b__]}:>{Callout[a, Before],Callout[b,After, LeaderSize->{30,45,5}]}, Infinity];
ListPlot[newcalls]`?

Comment: @kglr Thanks. :)

Comment: .. or `newcalls=Join@@Replace[GatherBy[call, First], {Callout[a_,b___],Callout[c_,d___]}:>{Callout[a+RandomReal[{-.001,.001}], b],Callout[c+RandomReal[{-.001,.001}], d]}, Infinity];
ListPlot[newcalls]`?

Comment: Why store such a small dataset in an image?  The question would be clearer with the actual data for `call` in it, don't you think?  It's quite small and easy to read, and I don't have to wonder what's going on when reading the question.  (That's especially true if *M* is inaccessible when reading.)

Comment: @MichaelE2 Hi, I think it is not a big problem. But I have fixed it by your advice. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:** Using Kuba's nested `Callout` approach is more robust than the jittering approach in my original answer.

The function `processCallouts` below replaces repeated `Callout`s with nested `Callout`s with appropriate position parameters:

```
ClearAll[processCallouts]
processCallouts[ls_ : 20, ns_ : 20, off_ : 5, o: OptionsPattern[Callout]] := Flatten @
  Replace[GatherBy[#, First], a : {_Callout, __Callout} :> Module[{args = 
     Thread[{a[[All,2]] , ArcTan @@@ N @ CirclePoints[Length @ a] }]}, 
   Fold[Callout[#, #2[[1]], Automatic, LeaderSize -> {{ls, #2[[2]], off}, {ns}}, o]&, 
      a[[1,1]], args]] , ∞] &;
```

**Examples:**

```
call2 = Join[call, Callout[call[[4, 1]], #] & /@ CharacterRange["A", "D"]];
ListPlot[processCallouts[] @ call2, PlotRange -> {2010, 2050}, 
 BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], Frame -> True, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[processCallouts[20, 20, 5,
    CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint", LabelStyle -> {16, Red}] @ call2,
  PlotRange -> {2010, 2050},  BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

```
call3 = Join[call, Callout[call[[4, 1]], #] & /@ CharacterRange["A", "Q"]];  
ListPlot[processCallouts[60, 0, 0, CalloutMarker -> "CirclePoint", 
   LabelStyle -> Red] @call3, PlotRange -> {2010, 2050}, 
   BaseStyle -> PointSize[Large], Frame -> True]
```

[image]

Surprisingly, this approach handle any practically relevant number of labels:

```
ListPlot[processCallouts[230, 0, 20][Callout[{50, 50}, #, LabelStyle->Tiny]&/@Range[99]],
  AspectRatio -> 1, Axes -> False, PlotRangePadding -> Scaled[.02], ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

```
jitter[epsilon_:.001]:= MapAt[# + RandomReal[{-epsilon, epsilon}, 2]&, #, {1}]&;
newcalls = Join @@ Replace[GatherBy[call, First], a:{__Callout}:>(jitter[]/@a), ∞];
ListPlot[newcalls]
```

[image]

Another example:

```
call2 = Join[call, Callout[call[[4,1]],#]& /@ CharacterRange["A", "D"]];
newcalls2 = Join @@ Replace[GatherBy[call2, First], a:{__Callout}:>(jitter[.25]/@a), ∞];
ListPlot[newcalls2, PlotRange -> {2010, 2060}]
```

[image]

Random jittering does not always produce all labels. More regular jittering using `CirclePoints` around the original point followed by post-processing to remove the added points may be the way to go.

Comment: There may be a typo. I needed to add an `Automatic` to `LeaderSize` to reproduce your result: `LeaderSize -> {{ls, #2[[2]], off}, {ns, Automatic}}`. (V11.2, MacOS)

Comment: @MichaelE2, it is probably depends on version/OS. It works as is in version 11.3 on Wolfram Cloud.

Answer (score 9):

Just nest `Callouts`:

```
ListPlot[{16, Callout[Callout[20, "right", Right], "left", Left], 35,  39}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks,trick, but it I want to label it with 5 or more different labels?

Comment: @yode I see kglr already answered. Next time make your question clear from the start. p.s. maybe edit it as it still says about two labels.

Comment: Note my question title have emphasized "two or more"...

Comment: @yode fair enough, why didn't you repeat it in the body then :p